# Tree view component with drag'n'drop leaks memory

Tags: vue.js, memory-leaks, drag-and-drop, vuejs3

I need to create a TreeView component in Vue.js 3, and I need it to be drag'n'drop editable.
The component I came up with is working, but it leaks memory.

Here is the component code, and a usage example:

**TreeView.js**

```js
var _draggingNode = null
  , _draggingFrom = null
  ;

/**
 * Check whether a node is a descendant of some other node
 * @param {*} node - The node to test
 * @param {*} tree - The ancestor / subtree
 * @returns true if node is a descendant of tree, false otherwise
 */
function isDescendantOf(node, tree) {
  if (node === tree) {
    // Recursion reached the node itself so the node is a child of the original parent
    return true;
  } else if (!tree.children || tree.children.length < 1) {
    // Tree is a leaf, recursion ends an the node is not a descendant
    return false;
  } else {
    return null != tree.children.find(elem => {
      return isDescendantOf(node, elem);
    });
  }
}

var TreeView = {
    //
    props: {
      tree: {
        type: Object,
        required: true
      }
    },
    data() {
      return {
        dragging: null,
        isDraggingOver: false
      }
    },
    computed: {
        hasChildren() {
          return this.tree.children && this.tree.children.length > 0
        }
    },
    //
    methods: {
      dragStart: function (evt, item) {
        _draggingNode = item;
        _draggingFrom = this.tree;
        item.dragging = true;
        evt.stopPropagation();
        item = null;
      },
      dragLeave: function () {
        this.isDraggingOver = false;
      },
      dragOver: function (evt) {
        evt.stopPropagation();
        this.isDraggingOver = true;
        if(_draggingNode === this.tree) {
          //don't drop nodes on themselves
          return true;
        } else if (isDescendantOf(this.tree, _draggingNode)) {
          //parent nodes can't be dropped onto descendants
          return true;
        }
        evt.preventDefault();
        return false;
      },
      dragEnd: function (evt) {
        _draggingNode.dragging = false;
        _draggingNode = null;
        _draggingFrom = null;
        evt.stopPropagation();
      },
      drop: function (evt) {
        var id = _draggingFrom.children.indexOf(_draggingNode);
        _draggingFrom.children.splice(id, 1);
        this.tree.children.push(_draggingNode);
        this.isDraggingOver = false;
        evt.stopPropagation();
      }
    },
    //
    template: 
      `<div class="tree"
        @drop="drop($event)"
        @dragover="dragOver($event)"
        @dragleave="dragLeave()"
        @dragenter.prevent
        :class="{ 'dragging-over': isDraggingOver }">
          <div class="tree-name">
            {{ tree.name }} - {{ hasChildren }}
          </div>
          <ul class="tree-nodes"
            v-if="hasChildren">
              <li draggable="true"
                v-for="(child, index) in tree.children" 
                :key="index"
                :class="{ dragging: child.dragging }"
                @dragstart="dragStart($event, child)"
                @dragend="dragEnd($event)"
                @drop="drop($event, index)"
                class="tree-children ms-3">
                  <v-tree-view :tree="child" />
              </li>
          </ul>
      </div>`
};

export { TreeView }
```

**vue-index.js**

```js
import { TreeView } from "TreeView.js"

var _tree = {
    "name": "root",
    "children": [
        { 
            "name" : 1,
            "children": [
                { 
                    "name" : 10,
                    "children": [
                        
                    ]
                },
                { 
                    "name" : 11,
                    "children": [
                        
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name" : 2,
            "children": [
                { 
                    "name" : 20,
                    "children": [
                        
                    ]
                },
                { 
                    "name" : 21,
                    "children": [
                        
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

const app = Vue.createApp({
    data() {
        return {
            user: Vue.ref(UserSession),
            tree: _tree
        }
    }
});

app.component('v-tree-view', TreeView);

app.config.errorHandler = (err) => {
    console.error("App error: ", err);
}

app.mount('#app');
```

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TreeView - test</title>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <h1>The Tree</h1>
            <v-tree-view :tree="tree" />
        </div>
        <script src="js/vue-index.js" type="module"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the leak after a couple of drag'n'drops:
[image: Memory leak detected after some drags and drops]

Looks like the "splice" where nodes get removed after drop leave some detached elements that retain other objects.

I'm relatively new to Vue.js so I might have missed something basic, but I have some experience with Knockout js where I managed to resolve this kind of things by cleaning event listeners or components manually when the default behaviour didn't meet my needs.
Can I do this in Vuejs? (i.e. in the unMounted method?)

Comment: From a running horse it looks like you just keep adding nodes to the children here `this.tree.children.push(_draggingNode);`. Might be worth a closer look.

Comment: I'm not sure I got your comment: When the node is dropped somewhere, first it's been removed from the original parent (`_draggingFrom.children.splice(id, 1);`), then it's been added to the node it's being dropped on as a children (hence the code you pasted, `this.tree.children.push(_draggingNode);`).